# c++ sqlite3 pthread error

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to build sqlite3 on my linux and use it in my c++ code.
However, after compiling sqlite3 and including `#include <sqlite3.h>` I get the following error:

```
.../main.cpp|52|undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'|
```

and after adding sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h to my project I get the following error:

```
.../sqlite3.c|20803|undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'|
```

I tried sqlite3 with both following settings:

```
gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl
```

and

```
gcc -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 shell.c sqlite3.c -ldl
```

Do you have any idea where the problem might be or do you know any SQLite3 CPP wrapper?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's bee resolved by using `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`.